# Programmable power outlets?

Tags: power, wifi

I've attempted to find programmable power outlets to replace the in wall ones. My goal is to replace all in the house and program them like a programmable thermostat. Ex: kids room tv enabled Saturday only, microwave enable between 7am-10pm. Preferrably they would be reachable to report their Watt usage, but ok if that's not there.

Do they exist? I know there are power strips that come close, but not ideal. I'm willing to make my own, but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Build your own

You could start with the [AC Me project](http://acme.cs.berkeley.edu/about.php)

### Buy stuff

[Various commercial offerings](http://www.powermeterstore.com/c112/measure_power_at_the_plug.php) exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know which stackexchange forum to post this question in.